# WiX GAC install and regasm for the same dll doesn't work

Tags: wix

I am creating an installer using WiX which contains few dlls. In the original script first gacutil.exe and then regasm for each dll  is called. I am having a problem when transfering this idea into WiX. Here is the code fragment for installing into GAC :

`<Component Id="GMAG.Core.Serialization.dll" Directory="_2.2.8.0" Guid="{my_guid}">
   <File Id="my.dll" Source="my_src" Assembly=".net" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
</Component>`

Now the question is how WiX will perform the assembly registration? My problem is:

1. I can't create another `<File Id="my.dll" Source="my_src" KeyPath="yes"/>` in the same component cause there must be only one keyPath="yes" attribute/component.
2. I can't put keyPath="yes" in component level, as it breaks component reference counting system.
3. I can't create `<File Id="my.dll" Source="my_src"/>` without keyPath="Yes", as it generates compilation error.
4. I can't create a seperate component as two components will try to install same file.

I know I don't need to call `regasm` or `regsvr32` when using `heat`. In the component code :`<File Id="my.dll" Source="my_src" KeyPath="yes"/>` should be enough for the registration.
I'm using heat and now I'm stuck as I have to do assembly registration also.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly=".net" will put you assembly in the GAC, you will then need registry keys for the COM registration. If you run Heat against your assembly it should generate the code fragment you require.

Answer (score 0):

That's how we register DLL in GAC via WIX 3.5:

```
<Component Id="Level0GAC" Guid="21735A8C-DD0C-4f4e-8AB5-B5BB8C55726B" DiskId='1'>
                    <File Id='Level0' Name='DLLFileName.dll' DiskId='1' KeyPath="yes"
                      Source='DLLFileName.dll'
                      Checksum="yes" Assembly=".net" AssemblyManifest="Level0">
                    </File>
</Component>
```

Indeed, there can be only one file inside a Component with a KeyPath set ot "yes", that's why for several DLLs you should create several Components.